# DexOpt: illegal method access with Gson TypeToken

Tags: android, serialization, gson, dalvik, typetoken

I don't know since when, but now when I deploy my app to an android device, I see these logs in the logcat console:

```
08-31 10:01:45.437 2157-2219/com.company.clap I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Lcom/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken;.<init> (Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)V from Lcom/company/clapcore/service/ClapService$2;)
08-31 10:01:45.437 2157-2219/com.company.clap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>, referenced from method com.company.clapcore.service.ClapService$2.<init>
08-31 10:01:45.437 2157-2219/com.company.clap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 15655: Lcom/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken;.<init> (Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)V
08-31 10:01:45.437 2157-2219/com.company.clap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0033
08-31 10:01:45.767 2157-2219/com.company.clap I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Lcom/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken;.<init> (Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)V from Lcom/company/clapcore/service/ClapService$1;)
08-31 10:01:45.767 2157-2219/com.company.clap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>, referenced from method com.company.clapcore.service.ClapService$1.<init>
08-31 10:01:45.767 2157-2219/com.company.clap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 15655: Lcom/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken;.<init> (Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)V
08-31 10:01:45.767 2157-2219/com.company.clap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0033
```

There doesn't seems to be any problem related to that, my app is still working but I hate to see errors in the booting sequence and I'm afraid that it could hide some bugs later on.

The `ClapService` class simply import the TypeToken package like this:

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
```

And use it in various way, like these:

```
private Object getPartialConfig(String settingName, TypeToken<?> typeToken) {
...
}
```

Or Something like this:

```
private LocalizationConfig getLocalizationConfig() {
        return (LocalizationConfig)getPartialConfig("localizationSettings", new TypeToken<LocalizationConfig>() {});
    }
```

If somebody can explain me this error and tell me how to get rid of it, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I've got pretty much the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet. Still have the same info in the logs!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty constructor to `ClapService`

```
public ClapService() {
}
```

Comment: With the latest IntelliJ installed, the error stop showing... Maybe it was a bug on their side. I will let the question open for the moment and check if the error come back.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté I've made a correction to my answer, you should give it a go

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté Also, this probably has nothing to do with the IntelliJ version you're running. More likely with the gson library version you used in your project